# How to save game status in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, autosave

I have lots (up to hundreds of thousand) of graphics object created by as3 classes.I know that I can save parameters of the game in shared objects to use them when program restarts, but it seems it is not good enough. I want to save exact picture|status of all graphic objects to redraw them when program restarts. Is there a good way to do that? Is there limitations on size or number of shared objects to save types, sizes, coordinates, colors, and etc. of all of the thousands of objects?

Comment: **SharedObject** is good enough, unless you forgot to elaborate on the part why it is more unsuitable than just your feeling.

Comment: What steps have you taken to try to fix this? Have you looked at the SharedObject documentation to find out why it's not working in your case? I have experience using them and could help if you provide more information as to how you're implementing them.

Comment: @ugotopia123 From my *experience*, the questions like this is not actually about using **SharedObject** (which is totally trivial and shouldn't pose a problem), but about building a (**JSON**-compatible, so it actually **can** be stored to **SharedObject**) data model that represents a precise snapshot of the application state and can be used to accurately restore it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.